# how to change default window size

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am creating a simle application on iphone.
I am using self.editButtonItem....The code belw used for that...
I want to change its frame size.For that i use

```
self.editButtonItem.frame=(0,0,248,31);
```

it is not working....

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem; 
self.editButtonItem.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
self.editButtonItem.frame = (0,0,248,31);
self.editButtonItem.title = @"Edit";
```

How to set `self.editButtonItem` frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CGRectMake function

```
self.editButtonItem.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,248,31);
```

Or [compound literal](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-02-18-compound-literals.html) if you want:

```
self.editButtonItem.frame = (CGRect){0,0,248,31};
```